# SpringApplication sub-classing

Tags: spring-boot

I have sub-classed SpringApplication in order to perform a recursive bootstrap:

```
package platform;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class ContextOverrideSpringApplication extends SpringApplication {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext overridingApplicationContext;

    public ContextOverrideSpringApplication(Class src, ConfigurableApplicationContext overridingApplicationContext) {
        super(src);
        this.overridingApplicationContext = overridingApplicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void postProcessApplicationContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {

        Utils.mergeProperties(context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources(),
                overridingApplicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources(),true);
        DefaultListableBeanFactory  appBeanFact = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory();
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory ovrBeanFact = overridingApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();
        for (String beanName : ovrBeanFact.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            if (appBeanFact.containsBeanDefinition(beanName)) {
                appBeanFact.removeBeanDefinition(beanName);
            }
            appBeanFact.registerBeanDefinition(beanName,ovrBeanFact.getBeanDefinition(beanName));
        }
    }

}
```

When I call this using run(args...) it works, but using a different run, e.g. run(Target.class), the overrides are not applied.

What am I doing wrong here?

Amended:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {
    public static String BOOT_STRAPPER_NAME = "bootStrapper";

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        CommandLinePropertySource commandLinePropertySource = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
        MutablePropertySources mutProps = new MutablePropertySources();
        mutProps.addLast(commandLinePropertySource);
        PropertySources propSources = mutProps;

        Class target = MySpringBootApplication.class;

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext bootCtx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        bootCtx.scan(MySpringBootApplication.class.getPackage().getName());
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = bootCtx;

        while (ctx.containsBean(BOOT_STRAPPER_NAME)) {
            // run the boot strapper
            BootStrapper bootStrapper = (BootStrapper) ctx.getBeanFactory().getBean(BOOT_STRAPPER_NAME);
            System.out.println("Running bootStrapper: " + bootStrapper.getClass().getTypeName());
            bootStrapper.setCallingContext(ctx);
            bootStrapper.init();
            ctx = bootStrapper.getCalledContext();
        }

        // initialise with overrides
        ContextOverrideSpringApplication app = new ContextOverrideSpringApplication(target,ctx);
        ctx = app.run(args);  // can't use a config class here

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you specify both commands exactly what you are using !!!

Comment: this works: 

    ctx = app.run(args);

Comment: this does not work(it gives the default SpringApplication class behaviour, even though app is a ContextOverrideSpringApplication):

    ctx = app.run(Target.class);

Comment: Can you share your complete code (method from where you calling RUN) to emulate the issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem after looking at the source in grepcode.com .  The issue is kind of a bug in SpringApplication.

The run() method with just args is dynamic, so it will call my overridden methods.

But the other two run() methods are static.  The code for these instantiates a SpringApplication class object, and then calls run on that.  So my overrides in ContextOverrideSpringApplication are ignored.